# Is there a way to name a property by string on object creation?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to name a object property directly inside the object declaration itself, insted of doing it afterwards?

For examle, this works:

```
var name  = "foo";
var obj   = {};
obj[name] = "bar; // obj.foo === "bar"
```

But is there a way to do it somehow inside the object itself, like:

```
var name  = "foo";
var obj   = {
    name: "bar" // obj.name === "bar"
};
```

I know it is possible to use strings for property names, so I was thinking something like this should do as workaround, but it didn't:

```
var obj   = {
    "" + name: "bar"
};
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you have a preferred duplicate? How about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal?

Comment: @eisbehr: this has been asked and answered about 1e10 times before, please use the search next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is in ES2015, otherwise in ES5, there is no way to do that

```js
var name = "foo";
var obj = {
  [name]: "bar"
};

console.log(obj)
```

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, the object initializer syntax also
>   supports computed property names. That allows you to put an expression
>   in brackets `[]`, that will be computed as the property name. This is
>   symmetrical to the bracket notation of the property accessor syntax,
>   which you might have used to read and set properties already. Now you
>   can use the same syntax in object literals, too.

[**Computed properties in object initializers on MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

Comment: it's called computed property name.

Comment: Your comment says ->  // obj.name === 'bar',    didn't you mean obj.foo === 'bar'?.

Comment: I'm glad I work with node, so there is no problem using this! ;) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Keith think he copied my example. Was so kind to edit it ...

Comment: @eisbehr - yes, I just copy pasted the code in your question, and added the brackets